# Module 'null' not found error

Tags: jsp, struts-1

Now I am using Apache Tomcat server. I wrote a project using Struts framework.
My jsp page can't run. Whenever I run , Module 'null' not found error occur. How can I solve this error?

Here is signup1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="/SignUpPath">
First Name<html:text property="first"></html:text>
LastName<html:text property="last"></html:text>
Email<html:text property="email"></html:text>
Phone<html:text property="phone"></html:text>
<html:submit value="Login"></html:submit>
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>
<form-beans>
<form-bean
        name="SignUpName"
        type="presentation.form.SignUpForm">

 </form-bean>

</form-beans>


<action-mappings>


    <action
        path="/SignUpPath"
        type="presentation.action.SignUpAction"
        name="SignUpName"
        scope="request"

        input="/jsp/signup1.jsp">
<forward name="success" path="/jsp/signup2.jsp"></forward>    
</action-mappings>


<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
<set-property
    property="pathnames"
    value="/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml,
           /WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
 </plug-in>

</struts-config>
```

Here is SignUpAction.java

```
package presentation.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class SignUpAction extends Action{
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm    form,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse rep)

{
System.out.println("You are now in ActionClass");
return mapping.findForward("success");

}
```

Here is SignUpForm.java

```
package presentation.form;

public class SignUpForm {
private String first;
private String last;
private String email;
private String phone;
public String getFirst() {
return first;
}
public void setFirst(String first) {
this.first = first;
}
public String getLast() {
return last;
}
public void setLast(String last) {
this.last = last;
}
public String getEmail() {
return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}
public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

Here is Error [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaVA2.png)

Comment: Show your jsp and controller

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Now I have been edited. Please help me.

Comment: With the information provided the help is impossible.